# cq 6.0 How i can allow upload svg files to dam

Tags: svg, aem, dam

I am using cq 6.0. How i can allow upload svg files to dam.
When i trying, i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOfj9.png). I found [there](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/content/assets/assets-formats.html), that mime type for svg is image/svg+xml. Tried to add this type to Adobe CQ Scene7 Asset MIME type Service (from /system/console/configMgr), but it didn't help.

> **Error**
>
> The following file has an invalid extension or its name contains some
>   illegal characters or spaces:
>
> mysvg.svg
>
> The file name should contain only alphanumeric characters and dashes
>   and underscores. Jpg, jpeg, gif, png, bmp, swf, flv, avi, mp3, mp4,
>   mov, wmv, mpg, mkv, xml, xlsx, pdf, ics - all valid extensions.

**Upd 6/8/2016**
It was forbidden by overridden DialogUtils.js

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you copy the error directly into the question (text or include image instead of just linking to the image). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The extension is valid and your file's name doesn't contains some illegal characters.
The only way I found to obtain this message, with a correct file, is by adding some spaces to the end of the field (after the text "mysvg.svg", like in "mysvg.svg ") before uploading it.

Comment: It doesn't work: "There is a file with an invalid name. Please verify the marked field."

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this :-
Link:- **https://github.com/auniverseaway/svg-sightly**

You can find good answers by expert on AEM at Adobe AEM forum:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html

Thanks and Regards
Kautuk Sahni